# @OrderBy Annotation in Hibernate Not Working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
    import org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy;   
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;

     public class A implements Serializable 
        {
            @Id
            @Column(name="SNR")
            private long ASnr;

            @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name="B")
            private Set<B> bset;

            public Set<B> getB() {
                return this.bset;
            }

            @OrderBy(clause="bsnr DESC")
            public void setB(Set<B> bset) {
                this.bset = bset;
            }
        }

        public class B implements Serializable 
        {
            @Id
            @Column(name="BSNR")
            private long bsnr;

             public long getBsnr() {
                return this.bsnr;
            }

            public void setBsnr(long bsnr) {
                this.bsnr= bsnr;
            }
        }
```

For above code `@OrderBy` is not working. When i try to make `hibernate` query then only select query is showing on console and there is no order by clause inside the sql query.  Have i left something or written incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

you have used

```
 import org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy;
```

did you try with

```
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;

@OrderBy("bsnr")
```

I think you're misunderstanding what the `@Orderby` annotation actually does. According to the javadoc:

> Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued
>   association or element collection at the point when the association or
>   collection is retrieved.

```
The annotation does not dictate insertion order
```

Try adding on property or getter

Comment: import javax.persistence.OrderBy does sorting with HashSet only. Then i tried using  import org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy;

Comment: If you will look above code carefully you will see i applied @OrderBy annotation on setter method only.

Comment: @akki_java i cann see it on your setter

`@OrderBy(clause="bsnr DESC")
            public void setB(Set<B> bset) {
                this.bset = bset;
            }`

Comment: You put annotations on field or method, not BOTH.

Comment: @Billy Frost Can you share an working example code as i tried once by putting annotation on field and once on method but i didn't get any success.

Comment: "A working example" ? I don't use Hibernate, I quote based on the JPA spec and what works in the JPA implementation I use. Clearly, a Java Set will not have ordering (read its javadocs), so this applies to a List (if you converted your field to that).

Answer (score 0):

I added antlr-2.7.7.jar in the classpath and used javax.persistence.OrderBy in code. Now it's working perfectly.

Comment: Sure will take care of next time..:)